# @SpringBootTest doesn't start the test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a simple Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class WebAppTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getTopJsonTest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
                get("/api/v1/top")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

}
```

But when I start it, context loads and after that test not start... Infinity waiting... I really don't have idea what is happening :(

[image]

Comment: Looks like application not fully starts, because some initializations script running and go to the infinity. You can check logs and see inserts with EstateObject with addresses from Belarus Brest ). If you wanna test only controller for max speed of test execution create separate spring configuration without additional redundant dependency for your test

Comment: I found that spring shell block my test. It runs and waits for input. You must set spring shell property "interactive" to false and use it with @SpringBootTest